# Past perfect showing ability?

Tags: tense, past-perfect

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

"`I had been able to sing before I entered kindergarten.`" which expresses something that happened before another past action.

Not many grammar books mention this.

Comment: When you use "before" or "after", it is not absolutely necessary to use the past perfect tense. I don't see any reason why you should use it in the sentence.

Comment: Seems grammatically correct to me, but could be interpreted as meaning that once you entered kindergarten you could no longer sing. As compared to "I have been able to sing since before I entered kindergarten".

Comment: what about "I wish I had been able to play guitar"

Comment: That could be another question Tom. The only grammatical issue I see in that sentence is that some might argue it should be "...play *the* guitar". But I think it works fine without the "the" in some cases, for example "I wish I had been able to play guitar in the band, but they only had an opening for a drummer."

Comment: It seems incorrect to me, but I'm having a hard time articulating why. Rompney's suggestions below seem better

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/164942

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you mean other than general ability to sing which you may still have or once had had but later lost. So in your example, it is sooner the matter of choosing between *could* and *was able to* than the sequence of tenses.

Although using *had been able to* is grammatically correct, it nevertheless does make the sentence ambiguous as it was shown in one of the comments.

Anyway, singing can't be regarded as *a specific ability* that happens only once or a certain number of times in a particular situation where *had been/was able to* would be the alternative to *could*.

So, to avoid any equivocalness, the sentence should read:

*"I was able to/could sing before I entered kindergarten."*

> "Although I could read before I went to school, and I won the school
>   reading prize at five years old, my early children's stories came from
>   the radio and watching films at a cinema on Saturday mornings in
>   Australia. It wasn't until I was nine years old on a ship returning
>   from Australia that I was introduced to children's books."

Michelle Magorian (an English author of children's books)

Answer (score 0):

It's not just that it's a perfect tense.  This same thing can happen without a perfect tense.

> Ginger had 5 apples before she entered kindergarten
>
> Ginger **had eaten** 5 apples before she entered kindergarten

In this case, you can replace `before` with something else since your verb is perfect and in the past.

> Ginger had eaten 5 apples when she entered kindergarten.
>
> Ginger had eaten 5 apples as soon as she entered kindergarten.
>
> Ginger had eaten 5 apples on the way to kindergarten.

Generally, this usage is only ... used .... when we're telling a story.

> We arrived at the Christmas dinner at 3 o'clock.  Little did everyone know, I had already seen my presents.

Although, it can also be used to express a condition.

> Had I known who the winner would have been, I would have made a bet.
>
> I would have bought the toy if I had had money.
>
> He would have lived if he had had the surgery.
>
> The door would have been opened if he had had the key.

Compare that with this

> I would have bought the toy if I had money.

Now, we have a hypothetical situation.  In Spanish, this usage is called the subjunctive mood.  This mood is wishful thinking.  It's the same concept as saying,

> If I won the lottery.
>
> If I knew Spanish.
>
> If seven ate nine.
>
> If I could whistle.

When we switch things around and *perféct* the verbs, we have

> If I had won the lottery
>
> If I had known Spanish
>
> If seven had eaten nine.
>
> If I had been able to whistle.